# Invalid use of aggregating function max

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match(n)-[r:LIKES]->(m) with count(n) as cnt, m where cnt = max(cnt) return m
```

Above query results in following error:

> Invalid use of aggregating function max(...) in this context (line 1,
>   column 61 (offset: 60))

Answer (score 2):

This query should return a collection of the `m` nodes that have the maximum count. It only needs to perform a single `MATCH` operation, and should be relatively performant.

```
MATCH (n)-[:LIKES]->(m)
WITH m, COUNT(n) AS cnt
WITH COLLECT({m: m, cnt: cnt}) AS data, MAX(cnt) AS maxcnt
RETURN REDUCE(ms = [], d IN data | CASE WHEN d.cnt = maxcnt THEN ms + d.m ELSE ms END) AS ms;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to find a single node that has the most LIKES relationships leading to it, then you can add an ORDER BY and LIMIT:

```
 MATCH (n)-[:LIKES]->(m)
  WITH m, count(n) AS cnt
 ORDER BY cnt DESC
 LIMIT 1
RETURN m
```

However, that query has the limitation in that if more than one node has the maximum number of inbound relationships, then those tied nodes won't be returned.  To achieve that result, you might try something like this:

```
 MATCH (n)-[:LIKES]->(m)
  WITH m, count(n) AS cnt
  WITH MAX(cnt) AS maxcnt
 MATCH (o)
 WHERE size((o)<-[:LIKES]-()) = maxcnt
RETURN o
```